# trouble getting pylint to find inherited methods in pylons/SA models

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pylons, pylint

I have a Pylons app that I'm using SqlAlchemy declarative models for. In order to make the code a bit cleaner I add a .query onto the SA Base and inherit all my models from that.

So in my app.model.meta I have

```
Base = declarative_base()
metadata = Base.metadata
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker())

Base.query = Session.query_property(Query)
```

I think inherit this into app.model.mymodel and declare it as a child of meta.Base. This lets me write my queries as

```
mymodel.query.filter(mymodel.id == 3).all()
```

The trouble is that pylint is not seeing .query as a valid attribute of my models.

```
E:102:JobCounter.reset_count: Class 'JobCounter' has no 'query' member
```

Obviously this error is all over the place since it occurs on any model doing any query. I don't want to just skip the error because it might point out something down the road on non-orm classes, but I must be missing something for pylint to accept this.

Any hints?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Best I could find for this is to pass pylint a list of classes to ignore this check on.  It'll still do other checks for these classes, you'll just have to maintain a list of these somewhere:

`pylint --ignored-classes=MyModel1,MyModel2 myfile.py`

I know it's not ideal, but there's something about the way that sqlalchemy sets up the models that confuses pylint.  At least with this you still get the check for non-orm classes.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion, but what I did was to use the generated-members flag to pylint. I ended up creating a pylintrc that is checked into git with each project and added such as: generated-members=commit,query,add,delete